# Nested form: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find SubWorking with ID=235 for WorkingEstimate with ID=20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

When we create nested form we don't have any error, also when we add and update some record it's OK too.

When I create its save ids but when I am going to update and deselect and try to update. Why I got this kind off error?

But when we deselect some record (uncheck the checkbox) it shows the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/projects/10
Couldn't find SubWorking with ID=235 for WorkingEstimate with ID=20
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/projects/10
Couldn't find WorkingEstimate with ID=20 for Project with ID=10
```

Please see: https://gist.github.com/saroar/b7ea214c422a940295544d6bdc3e55b1

```
= semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @project] do |f|
  = f.inputs "Project Details" do
    = f.input :start_date, as: :date_picker
    = f.input :doc_name
    = f.input :project_name
    = f.input :end_date, as: :date_picker
    = f.input :company_id, as: :select, collection: Company.all.map {|c| [c.company_name, c.id]}
    = f.input :working_estimate_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: WorkingEstimate.all.map {|c| [c.working_title, c.id]}

    br
    = f.inputs 'Working Estimates' do
      = f.semantic_fields_for :working_estimates do |we|
        br
        = we.input :working_title 
        = we.input :sub_working_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: SubWorking.all.map { |s| [s.sub_working_title, s.id] }

        br
        br
        = we.inputs 'Sub Workings' do
          = we.semantic_fields_for :sub_workings do |sw|
            br
            = sw.input :sub_working_title
            = sw.input :working_hour
            br
            = sw.input :specialist_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Specialist.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
            br
            - if sw.object.nil?
              = sw.inputs 'Specialist' do
                br
                = sw.semantic_fields_for :specialists do |s|
                  br
                  = s.input :name
                  = s.input :rate
                  br

  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit
    = f.action :cancel

ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  permit_params :start_date, :end_date, :doc_name, :project_name, :company_id, working_estimate_ids: [],
                working_estimates_attributes: [:id, :working_title, :_update, :_destroy, sub_working_ids: [],
                sub_workings_attributes: [:id ,:sub_working_title, :working_hour,:_update, :_destroy, specialist_ids: [],
                specialist_attributes: [:id, :name, :rate, :_update, :_destroy] ]]
```

Database migrations:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160720174415) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree

  create_table "authentication_providers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "authentication_providers", ["name"], name: "index_name_on_authentication_providers", using: :btree

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "ancestry"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["ancestry"], name: "index_comments_on_ancestry", using: :btree
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "companies", ["user_id"], name: "index_companies_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "pg_search_documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "searchable_id"
    t.string   "searchable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.string   "doc_name"
    t.string   "project_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.integer  "working_estimate_id"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", using: :btree

  create_table "specialists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "rate"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "sub_working_ids", default: [], null: false, array: true
  end

  create_table "specialists_sub_workings", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "specialist_id"
    t.integer "sub_working_id"
  end

  add_index "specialists_sub_workings", ["specialist_id"], name: "index_specialists_sub_workings_on_specialist_id", using: :btree
  add_index "specialists_sub_workings", ["sub_working_id"], name: "index_specialists_sub_workings_on_sub_working_id", using: :btree

  create_table "sub_workings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "sub_working_title"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.integer  "working_hour"
    t.integer  "specialist_ids",      default: [], null: false, array: true
    t.integer  "working_estimate_id"
  end
```

Models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :working_estimates
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :working_estimates, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['content'].blank? }

class WorkingEstimate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :sub_workings, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_workings, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['content'].blank? }

class SubWorking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :working_estimate
  has_and_belongs_to_many :specialists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialists

class SubWorking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :working_estimate
  has_and_belongs_to_many :specialists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialists
```

The problem is when we deselect and update it give me id error but what is the reason can't figure out

when i select my working_estimate ids and save it

here is logs

```
Started PATCH "/admin/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-23 17:54:45 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Sfx0ajclKfily1JpT70rascb1FAA6VB4+BZQ0sQlCIQL+08GWu62lGae6SBt+uANHiRxR2Drj+U5kxCgUISq8Q==", "project"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-29", "doc_name"=>"COMMERCIAL PROPOSAL", "project_name"=>"MOBILE APP food delivery YUMMI YUMMI / iOS, Android", "end_date"=>"2016-07-29", "company_id"=>"3", "working_estimate_ids"=>["", "55", "54"], "working_estimates_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"working_title"=>"Research and design", "sub_working_ids"=>["", "265"], "sub_workings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Test", "working_hour"=>"", "specialist_ids"=>["", "28"], "id"=>"265"}}, "id"=>"55"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."id" IN (55, 54)
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 12]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "working_estimates" SET "project_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "working_estimates"."id" = $3  [["project_id", 12], ["updated_at", "2016-07-23 14:54:45.858884"], ["id", 54]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/projects/12
Completed 302 Found in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)


Started GET "/admin/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-23 17:54:45 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered /Users/alif/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7733d1fd5b7d/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb (243.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 265ms (Views: 256.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

when i deselect my wokring_estimate ids and save it

here is logs

```
Started PATCH "/admin/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-23 17:57:22 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lKtybJ9oaFy9GHcoyOTs+462pSDPSPM+dGIRI31x4hXWrEkA8qP3MH5NzGHqoyecV4kAN69KLKO151FR6dBAYA==", "project"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-29", "doc_name"=>"COMMERCIAL PROPOSAL", "project_name"=>"MOBILE APP food delivery YUMMI YUMMI / iOS, Android", "end_date"=>"2016-07-29", "company_id"=>"3", "working_estimate_ids"=>["", "55"], "working_estimates_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"working_title"=>"Research and design", "sub_working_ids"=>["", "265"], "sub_workings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Test", "working_hour"=>"", "specialist_ids"=>["", "28"], "id"=>"265"}}, "id"=>"55"}, "1"=>{"working_title"=>"Manager", "sub_working_ids"=>["", "258", "260", "262"], "sub_workings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Elaboration of scenarios (Use Flow)", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "28"], "id"=>"258"}, "1"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Development of visual concept", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "29", "33"], "id"=>"260"}, "2"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Illustrations, icons, animations", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "30"], "id"=>"262"}}, "id"=>"54"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 55]]
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 12]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "working_estimates" SET "project_id" = NULL WHERE "working_estimates"."project_id" = $1 AND "working_estimates"."id" = 54  [["project_id", 12]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
Completed 404 Not Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find WorkingEstimate with ID=54 for Project with ID=12:
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:555:in raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:482:in block in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:460:in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:343:in working_estimates_attributes='
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in _assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in block in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in assign_attributes'
   () Users/alif/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7733d1fd5b7d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:301:in assign_attributes'
   () Users/alif/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7733d1fd5b7d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:175:in update_resource'
  inherited_resources (1.6.0) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:45:in `update'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_rend

Saroar Khandoker, [23.07.16 17:57]
er.rb:4:in send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in __run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in _run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in process'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in process'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in call'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in call!'
  omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in __run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2

Saroar Khandoker, [23.07.16 17:57]
Started PATCH "/admin/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-23 17:57:22 +0300
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lKtybJ9oaFy9GHcoyOTs+462pSDPSPM+dGIRI31x4hXWrEkA8qP3MH5NzGHqoyecV4kAN69KLKO151FR6dBAYA==", "project"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-29", "doc_name"=>"COMMERCIAL PROPOSAL", "project_name"=>"MOBILE APP food delivery YUMMI YUMMI / iOS, Android", "end_date"=>"2016-07-29", "company_id"=>"3", "working_estimate_ids"=>["", "55"], "working_estimates_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"working_title"=>"Research and design", "sub_working_ids"=>["", "265"], "sub_workings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Test", "working_hour"=>"", "specialist_ids"=>["", "28"], "id"=>"265"}}, "id"=>"55"}, "1"=>{"working_title"=>"Manager", "sub_working_ids"=>["", "258", "260", "262"], "sub_workings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Elaboration of scenarios (Use Flow)", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "28"], "id"=>"258"}, "1"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Development of visual concept", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "29", "33"], "id"=>"260"}, "2"=>{"sub_working_title"=>"Illustrations, icons, animations", "working_hour"=>"24", "specialist_ids"=>["", "30"], "id"=>"262"}}, "id"=>"54"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 55]]
  WorkingEstimate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "working_estimates".* FROM "working_estimates" WHERE "working_estimates"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 12]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "working_estimates" SET "project_id" = NULL WHERE "working_estimates"."project_id" = $1 AND "working_estimates"."id" = 54  [["project_id", 12]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
Completed 404 Not Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find WorkingEstimate with ID=54 for Project with ID=12:
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:555:in raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:482:in block in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:460:in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:343:in working_estimates_attributes='
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in _assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in block in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in assign_attributes'
   () Users/alif/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7733d1fd5b7d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:301:in assign_attributes'
   () Users/alif/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7733d1fd5b7d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:175:in update_resource'
```

Comment: Please add the models

Comment: @PauloAbreu I've just added. Please see in the end of my questions. Thanks

Comment: @DimaStart, I also need the request logs, when it works, and when it doesn't. I forgot to ask :(

Comment: And the rails version you're using.

Comment: @PauloAbreu gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

Comment: @PauloAbreu please see update

Comment: @PauloAbreu https://gist.github.com/saroar/b7ea214c422a940295544d6bdc3e55b1

Comment: I need to see the controller code to `Admin::ProjectsController#update` but I don't understand why do you repeat yourself with `f.input :working_estimate_ids` and `f.semantic_fields_for :working_estimates`; they seem to do the same, but with different ActiveRecord behaviour.